# How do I resolve an "Invalid Transaction" error saving a zone config in Brocade Web Tools?

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, brocade

When trying to save zoning changes in the Zone Administration tool in Brocade Web Tools, I get the status "Failed to commit changes to fabric" and the messages window shows:

```
--- start of commit (Enable Config) at: Fri Jul 23 2010 19:43:40 GMT+00:00
Invalid Transaction
--- end of commit at: Fri Jul 23 2010 19:43:47 GMT+00:00
```

I've tried refreshing the config and just re-saving what is already on the switch, but can't get this message to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Web Tools.